# Can be java virtual machine influenced by missing national languge support in Linux?

Tags: java, linux

I don't have Linux. My program in Java reads an ANSI coded text file created under Windows XP in my national language. It worked properly under Windows XP. I'am interested if pure Linux can process such program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just install Linux in some VM. And Linux could be *configured* to handle ANSI encoding (not sure what that means *exactly* to you)

Comment: "*an ANSI coded text file*" -- What ANSI coding is that? There are many.

Comment: Virtual Machines are great for testing Linux applications

Comment: E.g. Virtualbox/VMWare, not the *Java* virtual machine

Comment: @Dolda2000 I'am using Windows-1250 - Central European Languages.

Answer (score 1):

The Java VM is certainly *affected* by language and locale settings, but just in what ways, if any, your program is affected depends on the program. String literals, for example, are stored in Unicode in the compiled program, so they will remain as compiled under all circumstances.

In your case, you seem to be interested in how `InputStreamReader`s and the like behave, and that depends on how you create them. If you create an `InputStreamReader` without any of the charset arguments, it will use the JVM's conception of "the default charset", which depends on the locale settings. If, on the other hand, you pass an explicit charset when creating them, they will behave the same no matter what platform and locale settings you run the program on.

For the record, a `FileReader` (if that is what you use) always uses the default charset.

Comment: I suppose that my code uses FleReader for reading single characters `FileReader inputStream = null; inputStream = new` Do I have a hope, then? But anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @user1382181: Just change it to use an `InputStreamReader` instead. It shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I already understand that which was not clear for me when I asked the question. ANSI is not natural for Linux. More typically it uses some extended ASCII (LATIN2 in my case). Java programming language probably knows both...